# How to fix ImageField upload in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to upload a profile image to the media folder, while this works perfectly from the django admin web interface, it doesn't upload from the api endpoint, it gives the media root with image name, but i cannot access the image nor is it in the location pointed to by the get_upload_path method. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**settings.py:**

`MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
 MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")`

**EDIT:**

**model:**

`def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return 'grey/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.category_name, filename)`

`class Category(models.Model):
icon_url_greyscale = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=get_upload_path, null=True, blank=True)`

**serializer.py:**

`class CategoryCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
def create(self, validated_data):
cat = Category.objects.create(**validated_data)`

**views.py:**

`class CategoryCreateAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
    serializer_class = CategoryCreateSerializer`

```
`def post(self, request):
    data = request.data
    print(data)
    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response({'status':True, 'message':'category created'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        raise CustomException(detail="Could not create category", status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)`
```

This is expected result:
'"http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/profile_photo/aafaaaaaa2a%40gmail.com/lol.jpg"'

This is what am getting:

"http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/test.jpg"

Comment: are you saving the image url in db? if yes, then what url are you saving?

Comment: yes I am saving it to the db, `profile_photo/aafaaaaaa2a%40gmail.com/lol.jpg` is what it is supposed to save, but only 'lol.jpg' gets saved. Have added this `def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return 'profile_photo/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.id, filename)` method to the model but it never gets called.

Comment: Can you post the relevant model code, including your `upload_to` function?

Comment: Please post your relevant models code and also function in views file for more information.

Comment: added the code, sorry for the delay was traveling.